# need to split a string within a cell into separate columns using csvReader

Tags: python

I'm using Python, csvReader to read from a CSV. One of my columns have multiple variables separated by a "|", and would like to write into separate columns. 
For example, the 3rd column contains rows of different transportation "cars|trains|airplanes|cabs", and would like to write to a new csv with four separate columns. Each cell can have anywhere from 1-5 variables. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do here. If you expand the 1-5 values from the 3rd column into 1-5 separate columns, the rows will all be different widths, not 4 columns. If you instead expand each row into 1-5 separate rows, there's nowhere for any new 4th column to come from. If you want something else… well, I can't imagine what that something is. Give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows where you want to insert the code you're stumped on and what the expected output is for some input.

Answer (score 0):

If the column doesn't need to be actually parsed like a sub-CSV (e.g., there's no quoting or escaping in it), you can just use `split` to split it:

```
col2vals = row[2].split('|')
```

---

If you're looking to replace each `row[2]` with the multiple resulting values, use slice assignment:

```
row[2:3] = row[2].split('|')
```

Or, if you're looking to break it into separate rows instead, just loop over the results and `append`/`yield`/`newcsv.writerow`/whatever you were doing with each original row.

---

If the column might have quoting or escaping, you can use `csv` again, by passing it a `StringIO` file-like object:

```
col2 = row[2]
fakefile = io.StringIO(col2)
subreader = csv.reader(fakefile, delimiter='|')
col2vals = next(subreader)
```

You can of course put the whole thing together into a single line, but I'm not sure the result is all that readable; probably somewhere between the two extremes is best.

```
row[2:3] = next(csv.reader(io.StringIO(row[2]), delimiter='|'))
```